# Why am I getting UB when printing a 2D array of char types in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, char

I am simply trying to print a string of chars using pointers but the output is not correct. Can someone tell me why? The method display_chunks() is meant to print each string in the array except for the first character. But instead seems to print the same line despite the fact that I'm incrementing the pointer variable after printing the last character in a string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//macros: constants
#define CHUNK_LENGTH (20+1)  //each chunk has twenty characters, we add 1 so
                           //there is space for the null terminator.
#define NUMBER_OF_CHUNKS 4 //the message is spread across 4 chunks.
void display_chunks();

char chunks[NUMBER_OF_CHUNKS][CHUNK_LENGTH];

int main(){
strcpy(chunks[0], "2i1%fsi%fs%jstwrtzx%");
strcpy(chunks[1], "1'H%nx%vznwp~1%kqf|j");
strcpy(chunks[2], "4R3%Wnyhmnj%%%%%%%%%");
strcpy(chunks[3], "3xzhhjxx3'%2%Ijssnx%");
    display_chunks();
}

void display_chunks() {
    int i, j;
    char *arr = chunks[0];
    for(i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CHUNKS; i++){
        for(j = 1; j < CHUNK_LENGTH-1; j++){
            printf("%c", *(arr+j));
        }
        ++arr;
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

This is my output:

```
i1%fsi%fs%jstwrtzx%
1%fsi%fs%jstwrtzx%
%fsi%fs%jstwrtzx% 1
fsi%fs%jstwrtzx% 1'
```

EDIT From Craig's answer; I don't seem to understand the difference between a pointer and a double pointer. What I tried earlier was incrementing arr because I assumed it would point to the next array in chuncks. Looks like I was mistaken and it took me a while to figure out.

Sorry, new to C : )

Comment: Read [mcve].  Provide a working example.  There are missing definitions.

Comment: What is `chunks` declaration?

Comment: Go back and read [mcve] again.  Edit again.  What is `chunks`, `NUMBER_OF_CHUNKS`, `CHUNK_LENGTH`.  Make a **working** example.

Comment: That still doesn't compile, but if you move the `strcpy` lines into main before calling the function it will give the output you say it does.  Really, how hard is it to make something that compiles and then paste it as is into the question?

Comment: Your code behaves in perfectly expected fashion, as written. There's nothing unusual in its behavior. Yet you claim that "output is not correct". How are we supposed to know what you consider "incorrect" here? What output did you expect? You have to explain that in your question.

Comment: "I don't seem to understand the difference between a pointer and a double pointer." Why are you mentioning "double pointer" and what does that "double pointer" have to do with anything here?

Comment: Don't ignore compiler warnings! You don't have a prototype declarator and the function definition is different from the declarator. If you got this from a book, get a better one. Also the assignment should generate a warning. Note that questions are required to have fix all common warnings!

Comment: @Olaf There is a prototype.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: That's **not** a prototype, but an old-style K&R declarator which was very different semantics! Read my comment carefully again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems.

Your for loop for `j` starts at `1` instead of `0`.

And, `arr` is always `chunks[0]` instead of `chunks[i]`

Here's the corrected code:

```
strcpy(chunks[0], "2i1%fsi%fs%jstwrtzx%");
strcpy(chunks[1], "1'H%nx%vznwp~1%kqf|j");
strcpy(chunks[2], "4R3%Wnyhmnj%%%%%%%%%");
strcpy(chunks[3], "3xzhhjxx3'%2%Ijssnx%");

void display_chunks() {
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CHUNKS; i++){
        char *arr = chunks[i];
        for(j = 0; j < CHUNK_LENGTH-1; j++){
            printf("%c", *(arr+j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Based on your original code [which did *not* show the declaration for `chunks`], the use of `arr = chunks[i]` was necessary because *either* of these might have been used:

```
char *chunks[NUMBER_OF_CHUNKS];
char chunks[NUMBER_OF_CHUNKS][CHUNK_LENGTH];
```

Now that the latter is known to be used, a variation on your original code is possible that uses the increment of `arr`:

```
strcpy(chunks[0], "2i1%fsi%fs%jstwrtzx%");
strcpy(chunks[1], "1'H%nx%vznwp~1%kqf|j");
strcpy(chunks[2], "4R3%Wnyhmnj%%%%%%%%%");
strcpy(chunks[3], "3xzhhjxx3'%2%Ijssnx%");

void display_chunks() {
    int i, j;
    char *arr = chunks[0];
    for(i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CHUNKS; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < CHUNK_LENGTH-1; j++){
            printf("%c", arr[j]));
        }
        arr += CHUNK_LENGTH;
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

A style cleanup of that could be:

```
strcpy(chunks[0], "2i1%fsi%fs%jstwrtzx%");
strcpy(chunks[1], "1'H%nx%vznwp~1%kqf|j");
strcpy(chunks[2], "4R3%Wnyhmnj%%%%%%%%%");
strcpy(chunks[3], "3xzhhjxx3'%2%Ijssnx%");

void display_chunks() {
    int i, j;
    char *arr = chunks[0];
    for(i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CHUNKS; i++, arr += CHUNK_LENGTH){
        for(j = 0; j < CHUNK_LENGTH-1; j++){
            printf("%c", arr[j]));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming the definition of `chunks` is sane, maybe.

Comment: Does that matter in this case? arr is a pointer and by incrementing it, it should point to the next array of chars. Am I correct?

Comment: @MarkTolonen More or less. OP's original behavior is creeping along `chunks[0]` and skips the first char, so it is somewhat sane

Comment: No, merely incrementing `arr` is incorrect because it's a `char *` instead of `char **`

Comment: @N Tesfai: No, you are not. Your `arr` is a pointer to `char`. So, when you increment it, it points to the next `char`, not "to the next array of chars", as you incorrectly believe.

Comment: @Craig Estey: `char **` has nothing to do with it. You can't use `char **` with the above `chunks` array.

Comment: @AnT We know that _now_, because OP edited the post to include the definition for `chunks`. It could have been `char *chunks[NUMBER_OF_CHUNKS]`, which is more usual.

Comment: @Craig It could have been, and would have been more incorrect, because of the `strcpy`.

Comment: instead of `*(arr+j)` we can use `arr[j]`

Comment: @CraigEstey: Something like `char *[]` is not "more usual" for a 2D array. It would be plain wrong, i.e. not a 2D array.

Answer (score 1):

To increment `arr` to point to the next array of characters, it must be the correct type, which is `char (*arr)[CHUNK_LENGTH]`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//macros: constants
#define CHUNK_LENGTH (20+1)  //each chunk has twenty characters, we add 1 so
//there is space for the null terminator.
#define NUMBER_OF_CHUNKS 4 //the message is spread across 4 chunks.
void display_chunks();

char chunks[NUMBER_OF_CHUNKS][CHUNK_LENGTH];

int main() {
    strcpy(chunks[0], "2i1%fsi%fs%jstwrtzx%");
    strcpy(chunks[1], "1'H%nx%vznwp~1%kqf|j");
    strcpy(chunks[2], "4R3%Wnyhmnj%%%%%%%%%");
    strcpy(chunks[3], "3xzhhjxx3'%2%Ijssnx%");
    display_chunks();
}

void display_chunks() {
    int i;
    char (*arr)[CHUNK_LENGTH] = chunks;
    for(i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CHUNKS; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", *arr);
        ++arr;
    }
}
```

Comment: My bad, unfortunately, sometimes UB stil works...the danger of vararg functions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variation of the Craig's answer using `%s`:

```
void display_chunks() {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CHUNKS; i++){
        char *arr = chunks[i];
        printf("%s\n", arr);
    }
}
```

And to print starting from the second character:

```
void display_chunks() {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CHUNKS; i++){
        char *arr = chunks[i];
        arr++;
        printf("%s\n", arr);
    }
}
```

https://repl.it/JKHB